# Remove default console white spaces

Tags: c++, console-application

I'm working on a small console based application with Visual Studio, and I want to ask if it's possible to get rid of the thousands of white spaces that the console produces on execution by default.

If I run the below code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

The console produces a load of white spaces underneath `"Hello World"`, so much that you can scroll down through it all. I want to be able to clear all of it so the scroll down option isn't even available.

I've added some images in case you're unsure of what I mean.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Is there a way around this?

Comment: This whitespace is not generated by your code. This is a property of your console.

Comment: Note: if you are using Visual Studio, you can run the program with CTRL+F5. Then you won't need `system("pause");`

Comment: Don't know if this will help, but try changing `endl` to `'\n'`. You don't need to flush the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No, this can't be removed.

This isn't your code's doing - it's how the Windows console works. Those empty lines are rows of the screen buffer that havent'e been filled with text yet. Running this on `bash` or other consoles like this won't show the whitespace - same thing if you pipe the output to a file.

#### However:

You can reduce the amount of whitespace if you want - it's a setting in the console properties. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1008648/1093046) explains how to do so, and [this one](https://superuser.com/a/1008823/1093046) lets you do it through the prompt or a batch file.

Comment: Got that working with the .bat file now, thanks again Nick!